# Figure with fill

Tags: plotting

I want to make a figure like this [image: This is made in geogebra]

In Mathematica 9, to fill it with a grid inside (and necessary without part of the grid outside), but to generate this picture, I need to graph two semicircles and a rectangle, so I don't know if its possible to do in Mathematica.

Comment: Have a look at the Circle and Disk commands. They have the possibility to include the third argument specifying the angles of the Circle/Disk opening. I would build first a rectangle and two half-disks at both ends, all with the Gray color and same Gray boundares. Then I would add on top two black lines and two half-circles, all in black in order to make the boundary in black. This does not address the grid part though.

Comment: What do you mean by "grid"?

Comment: Like the notebooks' pages, like this: http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/42600/42677/grid_42677_lg.gif

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should give you a head-start:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
With[{r = 0.025,
  x1 = 1.5,
  thick = 0.002},
 Graphics[{

   (* gray field *)
   LightGray,
   Disk[{x1, 0}, 1, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}],
   Disk[{-x1, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}], Rectangle[{-x1, -1}, {x1, 1}],
   Black, Thickness[thick], 
   Line[{{{-x1, 1}, {x1, 1}}, {{-x1, -1}, {x1, -1}}}],
   Circle[{x1, 0}, 1, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}],
   Circle[{-x1, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}],

   (* Lines *)
   Line[{{Cos[2.7], Sin[2.7]} - {x1, 0}, {-x1, 0}, {x1, 0}}],
   Line[{{-.3, 1}, {-.3, -1}}],

   (* Points and Label *)
   EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Red], 
   Disk[{-x1, 0}, r],
   Text[Style["LPK", 5, Red], {-x1, .08}],
   FaceForm[ColorData[1, 9]], Disk[{-.3, 0}, r],
   FaceForm[Darker@Gray], Disk[{-.3, 1}, r],
   FaceForm[Green], Disk[{x1, 0}, r],
   }]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

[StadiumShape](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StadiumShape.html?q=StadiumShape) can be used instead of *two semicircles and a rectangle* to render the gray field:

```
stadium = {LightGray, EdgeForm[Gray], StadiumShape[{{-1, 0}, {2, 0}}, 1]};
cols = {Red, Blue, Green, Black};
disks = Thread[{EdgeForm@Gray, cols, Disk[#, .03]&/@ {{-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 1}}}];
lines = {Gray, Line/@{{{Cos[5 Pi/6]-1, Sin[5 Pi/6]}, {-1,0}, {2,0}}, {{0,-1}, {0,1}}}};
rectangle = {Opacity[.25, Blue], EdgeForm[Thin], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.15, .15}]};
labels = {Opacity[1], Black, 
  Text[Style[Subscript[d, 1], 10, Italic], 3 {Cos[5 Pi/6] - 1, Sin[5 Pi/6]}/4, Right], 
  Text[Style[Subscript[d, 2], 10, Italic], Offset[{-10, 10}, {0, .5}]], 
  Text[Style[Subscript[d, 3], 10, Italic], Offset[{-10, -10}, {0, -.5}]], 
  Text[Style[L, 10, Italic], Offset[{0, -10}, {1, 0}]], 
  Text[Style[G, 10, Italic], Offset[{10, 10}, {0, 1}]], 
  Text[Style[ATM, 10, Green], Offset[{10, 10}, {2, 0}]], 
  Text[Style[LPK, 10, Red], Offset[{10, 10}, {-1, 0}]]};

Graphics[{stadium, lines, disks, labels, rectangle}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]